# Why does RewriteRule for "^//(.*)" (begins with double slash) not redirect to a single slash?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, httpd.conf

Have this rewrite rule in vHost context. But it does not rewrite requests that begin with `//.*` (double slash).  Just serves them up from `/.*` (single slash) instead of responding with a redirect to `/.*`

```
RewriteRule "^//(.*)" "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes plenty of rewrite rules.  All are working as expected.  Suspect that Apache is stripping the extra leading slash(s).  But I'd like to know for sure what is going on.  A redirect directive for // works.  So maybe Apache is not stripping the leading slashe(s).  Or maybe its where they are being stripped.  Maybe rewrite_mod strips them.
I'd prefer to use rewrite rule rather than redirect directive because I have some additional plans for this.  Like rewriting to a cgi script.

Comment: The answers don't explain why they are doing it, but the rules to remove duplicate slashes on this Stack Overflow question are all getting matched against `%{THE_REQUEST}` in a `RewriteCond` rather against the path in the `RewriteRule`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080652/issue-in-removing-double-or-more-slashes-from-url-by-htaccess   Maybe leading slashes aren't available to `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule "^//(.*)" "/$1" [R=301,L]
> ```

This will never match because the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against has already had all instances of multiple slashes reduced to a single slash.

To redirect such requests you can make use of this "feature" and simply redirect "to itself" and check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead in order to determine whether multiple slashes were present on the initial request. `THE_REQUEST` is the first line of the request header and contains the raw unprocessed request URL (excluding protocol and hostname, but including the query string) as sent from the client.

For example, to redirect all instances of multiple slashes to a single slash throughout the URL-path, not just at the start then you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

The regex `\s[^?]*//` ensures we don't match multiple slashes in the *query string* part of the URL (which would otherwise result in a redirect loop).

---

> Would `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^//` allow us to apply the rewrite rule to only those that begin with double slashes, ignoring all other instances of double slashes?

Not quite, `THE_REQUEST` server variable actually contains the entire first line of the HTTP request header. In other words, a string of the form:

```
GET /foo/bar.html HTTP/1.1
```

Or `GET //foo/bar.html HTTP/1.1` if there is a double slash at the start of the URL-path, so you would need something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s//[^/]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

...in order to catch all request methods. And specifically just a double slash, not triple slashes, etc. at the start of the URL-path only.

`\s//[^/]` - That's a *space* (after the *request method*) followed by 2 slashes and something other than a slash (ie. either a *space* for the document root, or some other URL-path).

Comment: Thanks Mr. White for the explanation.  Would RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^// allow us to apply the rewrite rule to only those that begin with double slashes, ignoring all other instances of double slashes?

Comment: Not quite, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay.  That helps a lot.  Thank you much.

Comment: Minor update to my answer... I simplified the regex that matches a double slash at the start of the URL-path. I also "corrected" the regex in the first example (to match multiple slashes anywhere in the URL-path) so as to avoid matching multiple slashes in the query string.